# Detail ajax.actionlink Open dialog and show detail about employee

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show jQuery dialog when I click on `ajax.actionlink` and request send to controller and controller return partial view and dialog show the complete data of partial view

Here is my code

```
        <td>

          @Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Details", new { id = item.emp_id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "#result", OnSuccess = "openDialog" });

                <div id="first">
                  <div id="result">

              </div>
                </div>

            </td>
```

Javascript

```
function openDialog()
{
       $("#result").dialog({
        title: 'Assign',
        width: 550,
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true
});


    $("#result").dialog("open");
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        var data=oj.GetById(id);

        return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/Details.cshtml", data);
    }
```

When I run the project and click detail link, no output is shown and when I debug the project controller return the partial view but no output is shown.

Comment: `UpdateTargetId = "result"` - the id itself, not an id selector